# How to combine two video files using directshow.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, directshow, directshow.net

I am newbie to c#. I have functionality of concatenating two or more video files using `directshow.net`. I have seen the documentation form http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375143(v=vs.85).aspx but i didn't understand how to start. I will be having two video files in the server in some folder. I want to combine those two video files and save as single video file. How can i do that using `directshow.net`. I am struct at this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

DES can work good, but keep in mind it has been discontinued. Maybe this page describing [how to append two wav files](http://www.informikon.com/directshow-tutorials/using-directshow-editing-services-des-with-c.html) can help you get started. See the [Time Line Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407192%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page on MSDN for an overview.